# VBA Dynamic Range to Extend Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do what seems like a simple dynamic range task in VBA.

[image]

The above table has data downloaded from an external website. New rows will be added to it every day.

[image]

This second table references the first. So for example the Date column in this table will be =USA!A18.

I want to write a VBA script so that whenever new data is added to the first table, I can run the macro to extend down the rows/formulas of the second table to add the new data.

So if 5 new rows are added to the first table, the macro will extend the existing rows and formulas from columns A to W  in the second table down five. It cannot have any blank rows or #VALUE errors without breaking some other code in the spreadsheet. The data starts in A9 and extends to W9.

I tried implementing the following:

```
Sub extendrows()

Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Worksheets("USA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

Worksheets("USA defprob").Range("A9:W9").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A9:W" & lastRow)

End Sub
```

but I get a memory error, which I suspect is because it's pasting several thousand blank rows instead of stopping. How can I adjust this code to do what I need the macro to do?

Comment: I don't know if this will fix it, but you definitely want to edit your last row line: `lastRow = Worksheets("USA").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`. Otherwise it is capturing the value of the last cell in column A, not the number of the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub extendrows()
    Dim nDataRows As Long

    With Worksheets("USA")
        nDataRows = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row - 2 ' assuming data start from row 3 in "USA"
    End With

    With Worksheets("USA defprob").Range("A9:W9")
        .AutoFill Destination:=.Resize(nDataRows)
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: that worked perfectly! I see what I should've changed in my code, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to dynamically adjust your range, place the data in an Excel table and let Excel do the work for you.  Select your data and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to turn the range into a table.  Excel automatically creates named ranges representing the entire data set, individual columns, and even for the data set without the header row.

So if the table created is called "Table1" then use the reference "Table1" to refer to all cells in the table except the header row.

Referencing individual columns is also easier as Excel creates named ranges based on the column headers you create.  For example, if your first column in "Table1" is called "MyFirstColumn" then use "Table1[MyFirstColumn]" to reference the table entire column (excluding the header).

If you want to know what named range to use for any part of a table, just go to a cell at least two rows or two columns outside the table.  Type the equal sign and then select a range in the table.  You will see for example that when you select multiple adjacent columns (data only, no headers) the range name looks like "Table1[[MyFirstColumn]:[MySecondColumn]]".